# Sitecore Forms "Null ids are not allowed"

Tags: sitecore-forms

When setting up my first Sitecore Form I'm running into some errors while posting the form.

In the log files I get the following error:

```
8700 14:39:03 ERROR Application error.
Exception: System.ArgumentNullException
Message: Null ids are not allowed.
Parameter name: buttonId
Source: Sitecore.Kernel
   at Sitecore.Diagnostics.Assert.ArgumentNotNullOrEmpty(String argument, String argumentName)
   at Sitecore.ExperienceForms.Processing.FormSubmitContext..ctor(String buttonId)
   at Sitecore.ExperienceForms.Mvc.Controllers.FormBuilderController.Index(FormDataModel data)
   at lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] )
   at System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<BeginInvokeSynchronousActionMethod>b__39(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ActionInvocation innerInvokeState)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`2.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3d()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<>c__DisplayClass46.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3f()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<>c__DisplayClass46.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3f()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethodWithFilters(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass21.<>c__DisplayClass2b.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1c()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass21.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1e(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecuteCore>b__1d(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<BeginProcessRequest>b__5(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

As Google was my first go-to I ended up at https://community.sitecore.net/developers/f/8/t/9790 describing the exact same issue, but no solution. I also see 2 form posts, the first returning a 200 status and the second a 500 error on the `Null ids are not allowed`.

With the help of DotPeek I ended up in `Sitecore.ExperienceForms.Mvc.Controllers.ModelBinders.NavigationDataModelBinder.BindModel()`. When adding a break point on that method it seems that the first post back does hit the line `navigationData.ButtonId = navigationButton;`, but the second post back doesn't reach that line. Because of the code optimizations it's hard to do some actual debugging in that class.

Questions:

- Does anyone know why the post back happens twice? (just curious)
- Any suggestions for a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Through the Sitecore community Slack I got a tip to check the custom JS, to see if it triggered the double submit. It turned out that jQuery was included on the page twice.

For me the issue was resolved by removing the jQuery scripts from the scripts field of the Form Item:

[image]

Update: In the end we only removed jquery-2.1.3.min.js from the form item and that worked for us. So not like the screenshot remove all the jquery scripts.